# Как присвоить дефолтное значение входящему параметру, если пришел null?

Tags: vue.js

Компонент ожидает на входе массив:

```
props: {
    form: Object,
},
```

Есть кейс, при котором `this.form === null`. Если приходит `null`, как присвоить пустой массив вместо `null`?

Comment: Свойство default пробовали указать в prop? `form: {type: Object, required: false, default: () => [] }`

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишите, что компонент ожидает массив, но при этом указываете `Object`. Если компонент ожидает объект, тогда вот решение:

```
props: {
    form: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({})
    }
}
```

А для массива:

```
props: {
    form: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => [],
    }
}
```

Comment: `default: () => {}` не будет работать предполагаемым образом, т.к. JS воспримет фигурные скобки блоком тела стрелочной функции (и в результате будет `undefined`). Правильный синтаксис возврата объекта описанного пустым литералом - через скобки: `default: () => ({})`.

Comment: @yar85 да, согласен, пока копипастил из IDE где-то потерял.